# RecyclerView onClick notifyItemRemoved doesn't trigger onBindView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I use `notifyItemRemoved()` method I want to change other remaining item , but the method doesn't trigger `onBindView()` method.

How can I do that, except using the `notifyDataSetChanged()`. I want to have the animation that comes with `notifyItemRemoved()` method

Answer (score 49, accepted):

If you are trying to remove an item from `RecyclerView Adapter` and want to show animation all over your list in `RecyclerView`.

after using `notifyItemRemoved(position)` use `notifyItemRangeChanged(position, getItemCount());`

> **notifyItemRemoved(position);** - notifies the RecyclerView Adapter that data in adapter has been removed at a particular position.
>
> **notifyItemRangeChanged(position, getItemCount());** - notifies the RecyclerView Adapter that positions of element in adapter has been
>   changed from position(removed element index to end of list), please
>   update it.

Refer this [RecyclerView insert /remove animation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32890849/3140227) answer.

Comment: Encountered a problem similar but this ```fix``` should not do anything. Look to the RecyclerVIew code:  

        public final void notifyItemRemoved(int position) {
            mObservable.notifyItemRangeRemoved(position, 1);
        }

Comment: @VincentD. This fix does do something. Note that the fix uses `notifyItemRangeChanged` instead of `notifyItemRangeRemoved`.

Comment: You may also write: `notifyItemRangeChanged(position, getItemCount() - position);`.