# Recyclerview is not updated after deleting from the sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentprovider

I am new in android. I am using content provider for my app and want to delete an item from my sqlite database. it deletes the item from the database but the recyclerview does not show that it has been deleted except you go back and open the activity again before the deleted item disappears. I have looked through the code but I dont actually know what the problem is.

MainActivity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_selecte_problem_drawal);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));


    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.selected_problem_recycle_view); // Instantiate Recyclerview
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    selectedProblemsAdapter = new SelectedProblemsAdapter(this, null);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(selectedProblemsAdapter);

    getLoaderManager().initLoader(SELECTED_PROBLEMS_LOADER_ID, null,new CartLoader());


    payForSelectedProblems = (Button)findViewById(R.id.payForSelectedProblems);
    payForSelectedProblems.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (total > 0) {
                Preferences.setDefaults("total", String.valueOf(total), getApplicationContext());
                Intent intent = new Intent(SelectedProblems.this, SecondPayment.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }else{
                AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(SelectedProblems.this);
                alert.setTitle("Alert");
                alert.setMessage("Kindly Select a problem to continue...");
                alert.setPositiveButton("OK",null);
                alert.show();
            }

        }
    });
}
public class CartLoader implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {
    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle bundle) {

        return new CursorLoader(
                SelectedProblems.this,
                TranxavContract.CartEntries.CONTENT_URI,
                SELECTED_PROBLEMS,
                null,
                null,
                null
        );
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {

        selectedProblemsAdapter.update(cursor);
        total = getSelectedProblemTotal(cursor);
        problemSelectedTotal.setText(CurrencyFormatter.currencyFormat(String.valueOf(total)));
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader){
        selectedProblemsAdapter.update(null);
    }

    public double getSelectedProblemTotal(Cursor cursor){
        while (cursor.moveToNext()){
            total = total + Double.parseDouble(cursor.getString(SelectedProblems.PRICE));
        }
        return total;
    }

}
```

Adapter

```
  public SelectedProblemsAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    this.context = context;
    this.cursor = cursor;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public SelectedProblemsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_selected_problems_content, null, false);
    return new SelectedProblemsViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull SelectedProblemsViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    if (this.cursor != null){
        this.cursor.moveToPosition(position);
        priceIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(TranxavContract.CartEntries.PRICE);
        problemsIndex  = cursor.getColumnIndex(TranxavContract.CartEntries.PROBLEMS);


        id = cursor.getString(idIndex);
        problems = cursor.getString(problemsIndex);
        price = cursor.getString(priceIndex);
        formatted_price = CurrencyFormatter.currencyFormat(price);
        holder.selectedProblemPrice.setText(formatted_price);
        holder.selectedProblems.setText(problems);

        holder.remove_problem_from_cart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                context.getContentResolver().delete(
                        TranxavContract.CartEntries.CONTENT_URI,
                        TranxavContract.CartEntries.PROBLEMS + " = ?",
                        new String[] { problems }
                );
                Toast.makeText(context, problems + " Item Removed from Problem Selected" + "with postion " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                notifyItemRemoved(position);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return (null != cursor ? cursor.getCount(): 0);
}

public void update(Cursor cursor) {
    this.cursor = cursor;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

class SelectedProblemsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    TextView selectedProblems, selectedProblemPrice, selectedProblemTotal;
    Button remove_problem_from_cart;
    public SelectedProblemsViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        selectedProblems = itemView.findViewById(R.id.selected_problems);
        selectedProblemPrice = itemView.findViewById(R.id.selected_problem_price);
        selectedProblemTotal = itemView.findViewById(R.id.selectedProblemTotal);
        remove_problem_from_cart = itemView.findViewById(R.id.remove_problem_from_cart);

    }
}
```

Anybody who can help me.

Comment: where you delete the value show us your delete code

Answer (score 1):

For every delete, update your adapter like this

```
selectedProblemsAdapter.notifydatasetchanged();
```

Comment: should I add it in the main activity. Please help me with some code

Comment: @oshabzChuks you should do your own research, it is already available in stackoverflow, dig in yourself instead of asking for code

Comment: @AngusTay I have done alot of research on this. I have added notifydatasetchanged() on my adapter but it does not seems to work. that is why I decided to ask the question.

Comment: dont put in adapter .

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all your deleting process is correct and you want to show animation all over your list in RecyclerView.

Instead of using 
    notifyItemRemoved(position)
you could implement

```
notifyItemRangeChanged(position, getItemCount());
```

**notifyItemRangeChanged()** notifies the RecyclerView Adapter that positions of element in adapter has been changed from position.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33210414/recyclerview-onclick-notifyitemremoved-doesnt-trigger-onbindview/33211061) is a reference for you.

Hope it helps!

Comment: It animates the recyclerview but does not remove the item from the recyclerview

Comment: @oshabzChuks If it animated the recyclerview which means it has call the function, referring to " does not remove the item", I guess you did not even perform the delete operation, have you check your sqlite database data?

Comment: Yes I have checked it with DB browser for sqlite the row is deleted from the database but shows on the recyclerview

Answer (score 0):

May be the problem is the list hasn't been reload after you deleted the record in db. You can try the method `getLoaderManager().restartLoader(int id, Bundle args, LoaderCallbacks<D> callback)` this should be restart the query and update it from the db. I hope so. Check more at [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LoaderManager#restartLoader(int,%20android.os.Bundle,%20android.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks%3CD%3E))

Answer (score 0):

After Deleting recall your display method
    (If `selectedProblemsAdapter.notifydatasetchanged();` this method is not work)