# Android - RecyclerView Animation notifyItemChanged after notifyItemRemoved

Tags: android, android-animation, android-recyclerview

I am having an issue with my RecyclerView defaultItemAnimator. When I remove one of my items using notifyItemRemoved() I also call notifyItemChanged() on another specific index to change the text in it. During the removal animation, the item I called notifyItemChanged() on changes its text but does some goofy looking animation that sticks out like a sore thumb. (It moves to its new position instantly, while the rest move smoothly to their new positions)

Is there a way to get notified when notifyItemRemoved() completes so I can then call notifyItemChanged()?

Comment: checkout this SO Answer [Insert/Remove Animation Recycler View](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32890849/3140227)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution is to set a Handler.
Get the source code of the Animation class of notifyItemRemoved() and notifyItemChanged(). Inside the Methods should be the lines:

```
 animation.setDuration(getRemoveDuration())
            .alpha(0).setListener(new VpaListenerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(View view) {
            dispatchRemoveStarting(holder);
        }
```

Inside the     animateRemoveImpl() Methode.

Go to the declaration of the

```
getRemoveDuration()
```

And get the value.
Set inside a handler with a postDelay of the getRemoveDuration() the notifyItemChange().
Handler could look sth like:

```
handler.postDelayed(notifyItemChanged, theDurationValue); }
```