# Add new item automatically in Grid layout android studio

Tags: android, gridview

I am using note app in today
On that app if I delete any notes it will automatically do second note to be first position.
And I also want to do this in my app

How is this possible ?
I browsed in internet like this question but i have only little knowledge about this topic.
Help me how to do this.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This can be achieved easily using Recyclerview / GridView. Please provide a minimal reproducible example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: you can use linearlayout instead of gridlayout.
put two linearlayout side by side(both orientation vertically and height match_parent)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically what the note app is using is a RecyclerView whose layout is in form of a Grid. When you delete the note, it automatically updates to the note below the deleted one because of a mechanism known as [notifyItemRemoved()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter#notifyItemRemoved(int)) which basically takes the position of the adapter and removes it from the position it held. on the details of how to implement it in your project you can look up this previous answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32890849/13259575) . hope this gives you a little clarification of the beauty of android development

Comment: @SecurityCoding glad to hear that. Happy Coding