# Android Data Binding : Observable List to RecyclerView's Adapter

Tags: android, mvvm, data-binding, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

Is their a way, by using the `ObservableList` class from the new Data Binding library and the MVVM pattern, to avoid using `"notifyItem(s)..."` methods from the `Adapter` class?

Or if not what could be the simpliest way to bind an `ObservableList` to a `RecyclerView`?

Thank's for any clue !

Comment: Your question is a little too broad, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Have a look at following implementation of the `RecyclerView`'s adapter:

https://github.com/radzio/android-data-binding-recyclerview/blob/master/recyclerview-binding/src/main/java/net/droidlabs/mvvm/recyclerview/adapter/BindingRecyclerViewAdapter.java

It automatically notifies the recycler view if the `OnListChangedCallback` is called.

Also have a look at the rest of the repository. It shows how to bind your `ObervableList` to the adapter using xml. So that you can have something like this:

```
app:items="@{usersViewModel.users}"
```