# Android data binding ObservableList behaviour issue

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-databinding, observablelist, android-binding-adapter

I find it hard to spot the real raison d'etre of the `android.databinding.ObservableList` as a data binding feature.

At first it looked like a cool tool to display lists, through [data binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html), adding them via `xml` to a `RecyclerView`.
To do so, I made a [BindingAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/BindingAdapter.html) like this:

```
@BindingAdapter(value = {"items"}, requireAll = false)
public static void setMyAdapterItems(RecyclerView view, ObservableList <T> items) {
    if(items != null && (view.getAdapter() instanceof MyAdapter)) {
        ((GenericAdapter<T>) view.getAdapter()).setItems(items);
    }
}
```

This way, I can use the attribute `app:items` in a `RecyclerView` with a `MyAdapter` set to it, to update its items.

Now the best feature of `ObservableList` is you can add an `OnListChangedCallback` to it, which handles the same events available in the `RecyclerView` to add/move/remove/change items in it without actually reloading the whole list.

So the logic I thought to implement was the fallowing:

1. I start with an empty `MyAdapter`
2. When my items are fetched from my APIs, I instantiate an `ObservableArrayList` wrapping them and pass it to the `binding`
3. Data binding invokes my `BindingAdapter` passing the items to `MyAdapter`
4. When `MyAdapter` receives new items, it clears its old ones and adds an `OnListChangedCallback` to the `ObservableList` received to handle micro-changes
5. If anything changes in the `ObservableList`, `MyAdapter` will change accordingly without refreshing completely
6. If i want to display a completely different set of the same items type, I can just re-set the `binding` variable, so the `BindingAdapter` will be invoked again and `MyAdapter` items will be completely changed.

For example, if I want to display items of type `Game` which I have two different lists for: "owned games" and "wishlist games", I could just call `binding.setItems(whateverItems)` to completely refresh the displayed items, but for example, if I move the "wishlist games" around the list to organize them by relevance, only micro-changes will be executed within each list without refreshing the whole thing.

Turns out this idea was unfeasible because data binding re-executes the `BindingAdapter` every time a single change is made to an `ObservableList`, so for example I observe the fallowing behaviour:

1. I start with an empty `MyAdapter`
2. When my items are fetched from my APIs, I instantiate an `ObservableArrayList` wrapping them and pass it to the `binding`
3. Data binding invokes my `BindingAdapter` passing the items to `MyAdapter`
4. When `MyAdapter` receives new items, it clears its old ones and adds an `OnListChangedCallback` to the `ObservableList` received to handle micro-changes
5. If anything changes in the `ObservableList`, the `BindingAdapter` is invoked again, thus `MyAdapter` receives the whole list again and completely refreshes.

This behaviour seems quite broken to me because prevents the `ObservableList` from being usable within an data-bound `xml`. I cannot seriously figure out a legit case in which this behaviour is desirable.

I looked up some examples: [here](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=android.databinding.ObservableList) and [this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34019978/android-data-binding-observable-list-to-recyclerviews-adapter)

In the first link all the examples used the `ObservableList` directly to the `Adapter` without even passing form `xml` and actual data binding, while in the code linked in the SO answer, the developer did basically the same thing I tried to do, adding:

```
if (this.items == items){
        return;
}
```

at the beginning of his `Adapter.setItems(ObservableList<T> items)` to discard all the cases where the method is invoked because of simple changes in the `ObservableList`.

What is the need of this behaviour? What might be some cases where this behaviour is desirable? I feel like `ObservableList` is a feature added with data binding and is really useful except when used with actual data binding, in which case it forces you to defend from its behaviour.
If I declare it as a simple `List` in both `xml` data tags and in `BindingAdapter` signature, then I can cast it back to `ObservableList` inside `MyAdapter` and it works just fine, but this is quite a bad hack.
If it was just a separate feature from data binding, without triggering the binding at every change it would have been much better in my opinion.

Comment: If you add a single item to your ObservableList in your ViewModel, is BindingAdapter called again?

Comment: Yes, that's what happens, any remove/add/change to the `ObservableList` triggers the `BindingAdapter`

Comment: I would keep my ObservableList in my adapter in that case.

Comment: That makes sense, but my question is right about that: why adding a databinding feature called `ObservableList` which is better not being used with actual databinding (i.e. set throught xml), but must be handled directly in the `Adapter`? This just doesn't make sense to me, they could have done an `ObservableList` in their `Guava` library that notifies callbacks just like the databinding one, but doesn't rebind when passed throught xml. It's like building an object with a purpose and then deliberately break the desired behaviour.

Comment: It feels like I'm missing the right way to use the `ObservableList` with databinding, it can't be "just pass the thing directly to your adapter“ because then it would have been much easier just not to make it rebind every time it changes.

Comment: You are totally right. In that case `notifyItemChanged()` or `removed()` or other notifyItem methods are never called. Whenever you change single item, `notifyDataSetChanged()` method is called. Like you said, that does not make sense. I hope someone makes it more understandable.

Comment: You'd better use DiffUtil instead of setting OnListChangedCallback interface because your BindingAdapter will be triggered every time you add/remove something into ObservableArrayList. That's why, your list always will be reassigned or populated again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the example provided in the docs https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html#observable_collections the ObservableList is used for accessing it's items using key integer, i.e.:

```
<data>
    <import type="android.databinding.ObservableList"/>
    <import type="com.example.my.app.Fields"/>
    <variable name="user" type="ObservableList&lt;Object&gt;"/>
</data>
…
<TextView
   android:text='@{user[Fields.LAST_NAME]}'
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Therefore, when something is changed inside the `ObservableList` it triggers BindingAdapter to update UI. I think that is the main purpose of using  `ObservableList` for now while DataBinding is in development state. Maybe in the future DataBinding will be updated with a new `SomeObservableList` which will be intended to use in RecyclerView.
Meanwhile, you can use `if (this.items == items){return;}` if it works for you, or reconsider your logic of using `ObservableList`.

Comment: So if anything changes in the list, then the data will be re-bound and the text will update. This kinda makes sense.