# Remove RecyclerView adapter item from Activity

Tags: java, android

I have Quote List class QuoteListFragment. where I am loading data in adapter from server like this

```
private ArrayList<Quote> quotes;
quotes = response.body();
NewQuoteAdapter adapter = new NewQuoteAdapter(getContext(), response.body());
mQuoteList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

and RecyclerView Adapter called `NewQuoteAdapter`

I am displaying Item in details with `QuoteViewFragment`. I have implemented a button called "delete" in this fragment and I want to give the user a chance to delete that quote from fragment so When the user goes back to the list, it disappears from the list.
I have no idea how to achieve this. Let me know if someone can give me a solution for this. Thanks

Comment: Are you using any serializer for showing data ? you must share the code here so i can give a solution. do a paste bin.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove an item in RecyclerView- Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36858086/remove-an-item-in-recyclerview-android)

Comment: @BilalShahid I am using serializer called Quote for it. Thanks

Comment: All the answers below will remove the item from the list. But I believe the question you are asking is: How can I keep the deleted quote from reappearing when the user restarts the Activity. Since the quotes are being loaded from the data on the server. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well you have a list, and adapter, and a recyclerview

```
ArrayList<String> myQuoteList = new ArrayList<String>();
MyCustomAdapter adapter = new MyCustomAdapter(myQuoteList);
rcvQuotes.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Then in your delete you can just do

```
private void deleteAtIndex(int index){
      myQuoteList.remove(index);
      adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

//make a interface.

```
public interface fragmentCallback{
     boolean onQuoteDeleted(Quote deleteQuote);
}
```

have your activity implement the interface:

```
myActivity implements fragmentCallback{
     public boolean onQuoteDeleted(Quote deletedQuote){
         if(myQuotelist.contains(deleteQuote){
              myQuoteList.remove(deleteQuote);
              adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
         }
     }
}
```

then in fragment simpley

```
myFragment.setQuote(selectedQuote);
```

inside of fragment just do:

```
       @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        try{
            mFragmentCallback = (IFragmentCallback) context;

        }catch (Exception ex){
            A35Log.e(TAG, "Parent Context does not implement fragmentCallback");

        }
    }

public void setQuote(Quote showQuote){
     mSelectedQuote = showQuote;
}

btnDelete_onClick(){
    if(mFragmentCallback != null){
         mFragmentCallback.onDeleteQuote(mSelectedQuote);
    }
}
```

you can handle it by selected index of the row, or by last index, or first index, or you can add a long touch listener or trash can to the row item. how you get the index is up to you.

That's it, that is all there is to it.

Comment: Hi Priya, I don't see why that changes anything. Are you asking how to retain values? You can always keep track of the selected index as I mentioned so onClick "currentSelectedItem" or "selectedIndex" then pass to fragment Quote Object for display. If they click "delete" simply callback interface of deleteQuote. I will update my answer to show how.

Answer (score 0):

```
Arraylist.remove(index)

recycleradapter.notifydatasetchanged()
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the `index` of clicked item 
e.g index = 4
list of quote e.g quotesList.

```
quotesList.remove(index);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```