# How do I delete a list of objects from RecyclerView loaded in MainActivity from database upon button click from ChildActivity using Room

Tags: android

I have a `RecyclerView` in MainActivity that loads saved data from database using `Android Architecture Components` (`Room`), this data is then passed to ChildActivity via intent as a parcellable bundle. I wish to be able to delete this data upon button click from ChildActivity: the issue I have now is to get the `RecyclerView` holder position in order to delete this particular part of the `RecyclerView` data. I am aware this is easier by swipe to delete from MainActivity, but I don't want to do that since I will be deleting from ChildActivity upon button click from the context.
I have come up with the below method, but it's not just working;

```
public void deleteMovie( RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder){ 
    int position = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
    List<DataObject> movie = mAdapter.getMovieList();
    mDb.dataDao().deleteData(movie.get(position);
}
```

I don't know where to go from here. This method works well for overriden `onSwipe` method of itemTouchHelper class, but this is not my intention.
Kindly help bail me out.

Comment: refer this  may be use full https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46494987/remove-recyclerview-adapter-item-from-activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this data which is passed to `ChildActivity` contains the `ID`of the record in the Database's table? So, you can delete this record by `ID` or what you use for `@PrimaryKey`

If this suggestion not helps, please provide more code for better understanding

Comment: Your suggestion orientates me, I am working on a way to see if the data bundle contains the id as the entity object is defined with auto incremental primary key. I will get back to give you an update

Comment: Good to hear that and yes if you face with another problems just ask ;)

Comment: I loaded the list of object with its id and delete. I got the id via getId() I defined in the entity class. I never knew the id was in the parcellable bundle until you told me. Thanks alot

Comment: I am glad I helped. Could you vote up my answer. Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: I already did. The system only records votes from newbie like me but does not show it until I reach a certain reputation level. It's in there but not visible. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

After deleting the data refresh your adapter

```
 public void deleteMovie( RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder){
        int position = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
        List<DataObject> movie = mAdapter.getMovieList();
        mDb.dataDao().deleteData(movie.get(position);
        mAdapter.notifydatasetchanged()
    }
```

Comment: Kindly put more illumination on this as per how to use this method from ChildActivity since getting the viewHolder position is not so straight forward.

Comment: best you can follow this approach https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46494987/remove-recyclerview-adapter-item-from-activity

Comment: Thanks, but the link does not address my issue