# Recyclerview with footer not able to delete last item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, android-viewholder

I am using [recyclerview with footer](http://takeoffandroid.com/android-customview/header-and-footer-layout-for-recylerview/) everything is working fine. but i am not able to delete last item. Suppose we have 2 products in list now if user will remove one product then 1 product will remain in `recyclerview` then i am not able to delete that remaining product.

While i have one item it shows PACK ID null

```
genericViewHolder.removes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        packid=currentItem.getCart_Product_packid();
                        System.out.println("PACK ID"+packid);
                        deletetocart();
                    }
                });
```

ADAPTER

```
public class HeaderFooterAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

        private static final int TYPE_HEADER = 0;
        private static final int TYPE_ITEM = 1;
        private static final int TYPE_FOOTER = 2;
        private ArrayList<CartModel> idlistData;
        private AQuery aQuery;

        Context context;

        public HeaderFooterAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<CartModel> idlistData) {
            this.context = context;
            this.idlistData = idlistData;
            aQuery = new AQuery(this.context);
        }

        @Override
        public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder (ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            if(viewType == TYPE_HEADER) {
                View v = LayoutInflater.from (parent.getContext ()).inflate (R.layout.item_header, parent, false);
                return new HeaderViewHolder (v);
            } else if(viewType == TYPE_FOOTER) {
                View v = LayoutInflater.from (parent.getContext ()).inflate (R.layout.item_footer, parent, false);
                return new FooterViewHolder (v);
            } else if(viewType == TYPE_ITEM) {
                View v = LayoutInflater.from (parent.getContext ()).inflate (R.layout.listitem_buynow, parent, false);
                return new GenericViewHolder (v);
            }
            return null;
        }

        private CartModel getItem (int position) {
            return idlistData.get (position);
        }


        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder (RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
            if(holder instanceof HeaderViewHolder) {
                HeaderViewHolder headerHolder = (HeaderViewHolder) holder;
                headerHolder.txtTitleHeader.setText ("Header");
                headerHolder.txtTitleHeader.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener () {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick (View view) {
                       // Toast.makeText (context, "Clicked Header", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ();
                    }
                });
            } else if(holder instanceof FooterViewHolder) {
                FooterViewHolder footerHolder = (FooterViewHolder) holder;
                footerHolder.txtTitleFooter.setText ("Footer");
                footerHolder.FooterCheckout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                       // Toast.makeText(context, "Clicked Footer", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        if(userd > 0)
                        {
                            System.out.println("Positive");
                            Intent intent=new Intent(BuyNowActivity.this,DelieveringProduct.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            System.out.println("Negative");
                            String skipsid=String.valueOf(userd);
                            Intent intent=new Intent(BuyNowActivity.this,Login_Page.class);
                            intent.putExtra("proceedtocheckoutid",skipsid);
                            intent.putExtra("isCheckOut",true);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    }
                });


            } else if(holder instanceof GenericViewHolder) {
                final CartModel currentItem = getItem (position - 1);
                final GenericViewHolder genericViewHolder = (GenericViewHolder) holder;
                genericViewHolder.txtName.setText(currentItem.getCart_Product_Name());
                String pics = currentItem.getCart_Product_Img();
                aQuery.id(genericViewHolder.proimage).image(pics, true, true, 0, R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

                genericViewHolder.buynowprice.setText("$" + currentItem.getCart_Product_Price());
                genericViewHolder.buynowqtys.setText(currentItem.getCart_Product_Qty());
                genericViewHolder.discounttext.setText(currentItem.getCart_Product_packDiscount());
                subtotal.setText("$" + currentItem.getCart_Product_Price());



                genericViewHolder.edtcoupan.setText(currentItem.getCart_Product_coupancode());

                genericViewHolder.gocoupan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if(genericViewHolder.edtcoupan.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0)
                        {

                             couponcode=genericViewHolder.edtcoupan.getText().toString();
                            packid=currentItem.getCart_Product_packid();
                            System.out.println("Coupan Code on click"+couponcode);
                            goforcoupan();
                        }
                    }
                });
                genericViewHolder.removes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        packid=currentItem.getCart_Product_packid();
                        System.out.println("PACK ID"+packid);
                        deletetocart();
                    }
                });

        }
        @Override
        public int getItemViewType (int position) {
            if (isPositionHeader (position)) {
                return TYPE_HEADER;
            } else if(isPositionFooter (position)) {
                return TYPE_FOOTER;
            }
            return TYPE_ITEM;
        }

        private boolean isPositionHeader (int position) {
            return position == 0;
        }

        private boolean isPositionFooter (int position) {
            return position == idlistData.size () + 1;
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount () {
            return idlistData.size () + 2;
        }

        class FooterViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            Button FooterCheckout;
            TextView txtTitleFooter;
            public FooterViewHolder (View itemView) {
                super (itemView);
                this.txtTitleFooter = (TextView) itemView.findViewById (R.id.txtFooter);
                this.FooterCheckout = (Button) itemView.findViewById (R.id.footercheckout);
            }
        }

        class HeaderViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            TextView txtTitleHeader;
            public HeaderViewHolder (View itemView) {
                super (itemView);
                this.txtTitleHeader = (TextView) itemView.findViewById (R.id.txtHeader);
            }
        }

        class GenericViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
             TextView discounttext;
            LinearLayout lindiscount;
            EditText edtcoupan;
            TextView txtName,buynowprice,buynowqtys,buynowfreq,gocoupan,removes,firsttxt,thirdtxt;
            public ImageView proimage;
            public RelativeLayout linfreq,linqty;
            public GenericViewHolder (View itemView) {
                super (itemView);
                this.txtName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById (R.id.listitem_buynow_title);
                this.proimage = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.listitem_buynow_image);
                this.buynowprice = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.listitem_buynow_price);
                this.buynowqtys = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.listitem_buynow_qtys);
                this.buynowfreq = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.listitem_buynow_freq);
                this.gocoupan = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.listitem_buynow_gocoupan);
                this.edtcoupan = (EditText)itemView.findViewById(R.id.listitem_buynow_coupan);
                this.removes = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.listitem_buynow_remove);
                this.linfreq = (RelativeLayout)itemView.findViewById(R.id.linfreq);
                this.linqty = (RelativeLayout)itemView.findViewById(R.id.linqty);
                this.lindiscount = (LinearLayout)itemView.findViewById(R.id.coupancodeavailable);
                this.discounttext = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.listitem_buynow_discountstring);
                this.firsttxt = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.firsttext);
                this.thirdtxt = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.thirdtext);
            }
        }
    }
```

deletetocart

```
JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST, addtocarturl, new JSONObject(params),
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        System.out.println("response -->> " + response.toString());
                        cartlist=new ArrayList<CartModel>();

                        try {

                            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {

                                JSONObject person = (JSONObject) response
                                        .get(i);

                                System.out.println("person"+person);

                                String responsecode = person.getString("subTotal");
                                System.out.println("subtot"+responsecode);

                                System.out.println("person"+person);


                                if(person.getString("responseCode").equals("1"))
                                {

                                    JSONArray itemslist=person.optJSONArray("itemList");

                                    if(itemslist==null)
                                    {

                                        Toast.makeText(BuyNowActivity.this, "Your Shopping Cart is Empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                    }
                                    else {

                                        for (int j = 0; j < itemslist.length(); j++) {

                                            JSONObject cartitems = itemslist.getJSONObject(j);
                                            CartModel cvm = new CartModel();
                                            cvm.setCart_Product_Name(cartitems.getString("prodNarration"));
                                            cvm.setCart_Product_Price(cartitems.getString("finalPrice"));
                                            cvm.setCart_Product_Id(cartitems.getString("productId"));
                                            cvm.setCart_Product_Img(cartitems.getString("packLink"));
                                            cvm.setCart_Product_Qty(cartitems.getString("qty"));
                                            cvm.setCart_Product_packDiscount(cartitems.getString("packDIscDesc"));

                                            cartlist.add(cvm);
                                        }

                                        Toast.makeText(BuyNowActivity.this, "Product Removed Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                }
                                else {
                                    System.out.println("something wrong");
                                }

                                rcAdapter = new HeaderFooterAdapter(BuyNowActivity.this,cartlist);
                                rView.setAdapter(rcAdapter);

                            }
```

Comment: Let's say you pass idlistData into your adapter in an Activity A, then you can call idlistData.remove(index) to remove an item at this index and after that you have to call yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() and the view should update. So, maybe your data set changed but you didn't update the view.

Comment: additionally your adapter is too long for StackOverflow... you should remove any unnecessary code that does not reproduce your problem

Comment: @progressive_overload after delete data is updateing..but when it reaches last item i am not getting PACKID from sysout

Comment: can i see what your `deletetocart();` method contains ??

Comment: @jankigadhiya check i edited

Comment: see my answer below @AdityaVyas-Lakhan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a guess but you are **not parsing your `packId` while re initializing your list** after deleting one item.

```
if(person.getString("responseCode").equals("1"))
{

    JSONArray itemslist=person.optJSONArray("itemList");

    if(itemslist==null)
    {

        Toast.makeText(BuyNowActivity.this, "Your Shopping Cart is Empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
    else {

        for (int j = 0; j < itemslist.length(); j++) {

            JSONObject cartitems = itemslist.getJSONObject(j);
            CartModel cvm = new CartModel();
            cvm.setCart_Product_Name(cartitems.getString("prodNarration"));
            cvm.setCart_Product_Price(cartitems.getString("finalPrice"));
            cvm.setCart_Product_Id(cartitems.getString("productId"));
            cvm.setCart_Product_Img(cartitems.getString("packLink"));
            cvm.setCart_Product_Qty(cartitems.getString("qty"));
            cvm.setCart_Product_packDiscount(cartitems.getString("packDIscDesc"));

            // HERE add some code for parsing packId

            cartlist.add(cvm);
        }

        Toast.makeText(BuyNowActivity.this, "Product Removed Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Try adding the parsing code where i have added comment.

Hope this will help you.