# How to add dynamic views to the main layout in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-linearlayout, android-button

[image]

I am new for creating android dynamic views

i am having Root linear layout 
i need to add,delete views as showed image  to the root layout
in every view consist of two edittext,two buttons

how create,get each view uniquely in all the views

Can any one guide me,your response will be appreciated....

Comment: You can create the complete layout before hand and set the visibility to gone or invisible. When pressing buttons set the visibility to visible again

Answer (score 0):

use recyclerview , make a list and an adapter , onclick add another item to the list.

onclick on delete remove that specific item from the adapter.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26310638/7079340

this link will help you a lot in your mission
much luck