# how to re decorate recyclerView items below an item that is removed

Tags: android

I have a decorator that I Added to my recyclerView, and on the initial load and when orientation changes the decorator works great.  When I remove an item I want it to redecorate based on the new positions of the items after the delete but it is not working.

I have tried adding new decorators, that failed; so now

---

I thought that calling something like on the recyclerView would force it to re draw: it is executing the code but the background does not change.

```
 @Override
 public void onItemRangeChanged(int positionStart, int 
 itemCount) {
 super.onItemRangeChanged(positionStart, itemCount);
            Log.e(TAG, "range start: " + positionStart + " count: " + 
            itemCount );

            Runnable pendingRemovalRunnable = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mRecyclerView.invalidateItemDecorations();
                    Log.d(TAG, "run");
                }
            };

            pendingRemovalRunnable.run();
        }
    });
```

This is my decorator code:

```
 @Override
 public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView 
 parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
 super.getItemOffsets(outRect, view, parent, state);
 int pos = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view);

 if (pos == -1)
 return;

 String vid = ((RVAdapter)parent.getAdapter()).getVid(pos);

 mIsInlist = 
 PlaylistManager.get(view.getContext()).getIsInPlaylist(vid);
 mIsTop = PlaylistManager.get(view.getContext()).getIsTop(vid);
 mIsBottom = PlaylistManager.get(view.getContext()).getIsBottom(vid);
 mRegularLayout = (LinearLayout) 
 view.findViewById(R.id.regularLayout);
 if (mIsInlist) {
 if (mIsTop) { 
 mRegularLayout.setBackground(ContextCompat

 .getDrawable(view.getContext(),
 R.drawable.list_selector_playlist_top));
 } else { if (mIsBottom) {
 mRegularLayout.setBackground(ContextCompat.
 getDrawable(view.getContext(), 
 R.drawable.list_selector_playlist_bottom));
 } else {
 mRegularLayout.setBackground(
 ContextCompat.getDrawable(view.getContext(), 
 R.drawable.list_selector_playlist)); }
 } else {       
 mRegularLayout.setBackground(ContextCompat.
 getDrawable(view.getContext(), R.drawable.list_selector));}

}
```

Comment: did you try this answer on stackoverflow http://stackoverflow.com/a/26310638/3678308 ??

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Set your recyclerview adapter in **onResume()** method of list activity. So it will set again when any changes made on recyclerview.

Hope this helps.