# Remove Item on RecyclerView Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

How to delete an item on Recycler View in Android Studio after clicked an item? Here is my code now :

```
public CustomViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        namaItemView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.namaos);
        img_icon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_icon);
        img_icon.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v.getId() == R.id.img_icon){
            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "You choose "+sisop.get(getAdapterPosition()).nama,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: when onClick call back received remove item from the data list you provided while creating adapter and notify the adapter

Comment: @AbdulWaheed how to code it?

Comment: remove the item from underlying list by `sisop.remove(getAdapterPosition())` and notify adapter to remove that from the view by`notifyItemRemoved(getAdapterPosition())`

Answer (score 0):

first.. remove from your list using .remove(position), then `notifyItemRemoved(position)`, then notify range change `notifyItemRangeChanged(position, mDataSet.size())`

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
         list.remove(position);
         notifyItemRemoved(position);
         notifyItemRangeChanged(position, mDataSet.size());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When onClick is called use below code

```
yourDataList.remove(position);
notifyItemRemoved(position);
```

For further details you may refer below link thatwill give further deatils

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26076965/android-recyclerview-addition-removal-of-items
```