# Option menu in recycler view adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I would like to like to ask you how I call a method in activity from adapter recycler view.

[image]

In function buildRecyclerView there is set up the adapter:

```
private void buildRecyclerView() {
  offerAdapter = new OfferAdapter();
  recyclerView.setAdapter(offerAdapter);
}
```

In class *`OfferAdapter.java`* there is created submenu for each item and with *`onMenuItemClickListener`*:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(NoteHolder holder, int position) {
PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(mCtx, holder.button);
popup.inflate(R.menu.menu);
popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
  // TODO here I want to call delete item in MyOfferFragment.java
}
```

The main question: How I can call from `*onMenuItemClickListnere*` the function in `*MyOfferFragment*`.

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: please look at it my hope its helpful to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass a listener object in the constructor which implements by fragment OR activity

```
/**
     * item click interface of adapter
     */
    public interface OfferAdapterListener {
        void onItemClick(int position)
    }
```

This interface implent by fragment

```
/**
     * On item clicked Implement Method from adapter listener.
     *
     * @param position
     */
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(int position) {
        // Here you can call that method 
    }
```

then you pass this listener in the constructor of the adapter.

```
private void buildRecyclerView() {
  offerAdapter = new OfferAdapter(this);
  recyclerView.setAdapter(offerAdapter);
}
```

In the constructor, you can assign like this

```
 private OfferAdapterListener mOfferAdapterListener;
 public OfferAdapter(OfferAdapterListener mOfferAdapterListener) {
        this.mOfferAdapterListener = mOfferAdapterListener
        }
    }
```

Now you can use this listener by setting click listener on anyViwe like this

```
holder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mOfferAdapterListener.onItemClick(position);
            }
        });
```

It returns to call the method of onItemClick which implements this method.

**OR**

You can pass activity or fragment context in the constructor like above and call it through by it reference like this

```
((MainActivity) mActivity).methodName(arguments);
```

Here is `mActivity` reference context which you pass through in constructor.

Comment: Thank you very much for answer. Which approach is more "professional"?

Comment: @MarekVondra you can use listener it's easy, safe and more professional and please mark this answer if it's helped you.

Comment: Munir : I would like to mark this answer, but your solution not workiing. All cascade is only Overide method a I am not able to change it.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the `MyOfferFragment` to your adapter constructor.

```
private void buildRecyclerView() {
  offerAdapter = new OfferAdapter(this); // Adding fragment to constructor
  recyclerView.setAdapter(offerAdapter);
}
```

In `OfferAdapter.java`:

```
private MyOfferFragment mFragment; // field variable
OfferAdapter (MyOfferFragment fragment){
  mFragment = fragment;
}
```

You can then access `MyOfferFragment` methods via `mFragment`:

```
  mFragment.deleteItem();
```

**However,** I think it is a more conventional way to just move methods related to RecyclerView into the adapter if possible. You can refer to this if you want to delete an item from RecyclerView: [Android RecyclerView addition & removal of items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26076965/android-recyclerview-addition-removal-of-items)

Comment: Hello Saran,
I would liek to move this method delete in Adapter. But it is not possible, because in method delete I call startActivityForResult..

Comment: You can get that method from the fragment that you have passed into the adapter: `mFragment.startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode)`