# How to Delete Item by click in Item for long time in Recycleview?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

How to delete item by click in item of Recycleview for a long time (maybe 2 seconds) ? And when click in item for long time it give dialog : "Are you Sure To Delete?".

Comment: Here is your [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26310638/8956604)

Comment: How about add your code, so we see where we can help. Instead of pasting for you a code in general.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the asker has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if any), the expected output/behavior, and the output you actually get ([logcat logs](//developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat), [stack traces](//stackoverflow.com/a/23353174), etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to get. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Adapter class

    OnLongItemClickListener longClickListener;

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final DocumentViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {

        ...
        viewHolder.itemView.setLongClickable(true);
        ...
    }

    public void setLongClickListener(OnLongItemClickListener longClickListener) {
       this.longClickListener = longClickListener;
    }
```

OnLongItemClickListener

```
interface OnLongItemClickListener{
 void longClick(Item item)
}
```

After in your activity / fragment implements OnLongClickListener after call adapter.setLongClickListener (this)
in the method that appears, call alertDialog, when you click the ok button, remove item from the list and call

```
adapter.notifydatasetchanged()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add below code in onBindViewHolder method..

```
 holder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener {
val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        builder.setTitle("Delete")
        builder.setMessage("Are you Sure To Delete?")

        builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes) { dialog, which ->
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext,
                    android.R.string.yes, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

        builder.setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no) { dialog, which ->
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext,
                    android.R.string.no, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

        builder.setNeutralButton("Maybe") { dialog, which ->
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext,
                    "Maybe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        builder.show()
        false
        }
```