# Recycler View (with Data Binding Position is wrong after Scrolling

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

Im using Recycler View with data Binding to display a list of Routes.  For Testing there are always (and only) 10 Items (Route1 -10) Every Route has a delete Button, to delete the Row the User picked(From the List and from the RV). When deleting the first or second Item without scrolling, it works just fine and I can delete all Items. But After scrolling, (I think) the Adapter sets the Position to a wrong value and deletes the wrong items. Eventually the program crashes with a IndexOutOfBoundsException.

I tried to use other positions instead of the **int position** i get from the Adapter:

`holder.absoluteAdapterPosition holder.adapterPosition holder.bindingAdapterPosition holder.layoutPosition`

Unfortunately it didnt change the outcome.

Then I tried: [Kotlin RecyclerView delete item. Is this a bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64721270/kotlin-recyclerview-delete-item-is-this-a-bug)
Works better, but after deleting the last item of the List the adapter position is corrupt again.

Finnaly I wrote the onClicklistener for the delete Button inside the View Holder of my Adapter.
Now it works, but I dont understand why. Can someone please explain me this behavior?

```
package com.example.testnestedxml

import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.testnestedxml.databinding.ListItemBinding



class RouteAdapter(
    private var routeList: ArrayList<Route>
) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<RouteViewHolder>() {
    //Fügt alle Items (Views) in eine View
    private lateinit var binding: ListItemBinding


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RouteViewHolder {
        //View wird erstellt
        binding = ListItemBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
        return RouteViewHolder(binding)
    }


    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RouteViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val route = routeList[position]
        holder.routeViewHolderBinding(route, routeList,this)

    }


    override fun getItemCount(): Int = routeList.size
}


package com.example.testnestedxml

import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Handler
import android.util.Log
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.testnestedxml.databinding.ListItemBinding
import com.google.gson.Gson
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken
import java.lang.reflect.Type



class RouteViewHolder(
    private val binding: ListItemBinding,
) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

    fun routeViewHolderBinding(
        route: Route,
        routeList: ArrayList<Route>,
        routeAdapter: RouteAdapter
    ) {
        binding.name.text = route.name
        binding.dauer.text = route.duration.toString()
        binding.entfernung.text = route.length.toString()

        val itemPosition = layoutPosition
        binding.delete.setOnClickListener {
            routeList.removeAt(itemPosition)
            routeAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
            saveDataRouteAdapter(routeList)
        }
    }


    private fun saveDataRouteAdapter(routeList: ArrayList<Route>) {
        val sharedPreferences = binding.root.context.getSharedPreferences(
            "shared preferences",
            AppCompatActivity.MODE_PRIVATE
        )
        val editor = sharedPreferences.edit()
        val gson = Gson()
        val json = gson.toJson(routeList)
        editor.putString("Route list", json)
        editor.apply()
    }
}
```

Comment: What's in your `onClick` listener?

Comment: Can you post the adapter and the delete function of the listener code